# Magento - Print category attribute on category page?

Tags: magento

I followed the below tutorial to add a custom attribute to my Magento categories:
http://www.atwix.com/magento/add-category-attribute/

It seems to have worked as the text field shows in the backend and I can see the attribute in the database (eav_attribute).

The problem is I can't get the attribute to display in the frontend.  I have added the code suggested in the tutorial to view.phtml but it didn't work.

I have also tried

```
if($_category->getCustomAttribute()) {
        echo $_category->getCustomAttribute();
}
```

Any ideas for getting this to display in Magento 1.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing a reindex in admin

In Admin -> System -> Index Management